# titlesec extra arguments to sections

Tags: titlesec, optional-arguments

Is it possible to add extra arguments to a modified section environment using the `titleformat` command of the `titlesec` package? For example, that the section color appears as red when doing `\section[color=red]{My section}`

Comment: No. You'd need to construct a different command.